# ensure last admin remains while destroying/deleting/removing an user in devise authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin

I'm new to rails.I'm working on a small application which needs an admin role who can add, modify and delete the content. So some models/views should be hidden from general users and only admin can have access to them through authentication.

To achieve this I have used **'rails_admin'** and **'devise'** gems. I did not the want the sign_up page to be shown to genral user, so I have removed that removing :registerable from my Admin model.

Now everything seems fine but, when I log in through an admin, delete each and every admin from my dashboard, I cannot login again since I have removed the sign_up page.

So I want to ensure that my last user remains. A warning/notice should be shown user while deleting the last user. I wrote the following code for that

```
private
   def ensure_an_admin_remains
      if Admin.count.zero?
         raise "Can't delete last user"
      end
   end
```

This throws an error but my browser shows all the Error details. I want it to be shown to as a flash message. I think I have to change the devise controllers destroy method. But I don't know where to find it and how to do the required changes.

Can someone please help me on this?

Comment: Are you sure you want to delete other admins?

Comment: In reality no, but there can arise a situation where I'd have to give admin privileges for someone(known) to do some updates. I should be able to delete it later. 
What if by mistake in a hurry I delete even my role. The whole application(at least the admin side) gets locked. I dont want this to happen.

Comment: You'll have to provide some more info on what error you are getting.  If you want to flash a message just use flash instead of raise.  `flash[:notice] = "Can't delete last user"`
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Flash/FlashHash.html

Comment: I want a flash message to be shown, but I think we cannot use the flash in our model. I still tried to check it and I got
**undefined local variable or method `flash' for #<Admin:0xa71f3cc>**

Answer (score 0):

In controller...

```
def destroy 
  admin = Admin.find(params[:id])
  begin 
    admin.destroy
    redirect_to admins_path, notice: 'Admin destroyed.'
  rescue => e 
    redirect_to admins_path, alert: e.message 
  end
end
```